# Add values to column pandas dataframe by index number

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, filter

Imagine I have a list that represents the indexes of a dataframe, like this one:

```
indexlist = [0,1,4]
```

And the following dataframe:

```
    Name    Country
0   John    BR
1   Peter   BR
2   Paul    BR
3   James   CZ
4   Jonatan CZ
5   Maria   DK
```

I need to create a column on this dataframe named "Is it valid?" that would add "Yes" if the index row is in the list. Otherwise would add "No", resulting in this dataframe:

```
    Name    Country  Is it valid?
0   John    BR       Yes
1   Peter   BR       Yes
2   Paul    BR       No
3   James   CZ       No
4   Jonatan CZ       Yes
5   Maria   DK       No
```

Is there any way I could do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of a fake boolean (Yes/No), you should consider using an actual boolean (True/False). Then this is simplified to `df['Is it valid?'] = df.index.isin(indexlist)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isin` for index, that you'd normally use with Series, it essentially creates an array of truth value, which you can pass to `np.where` with true and false values, assign the result as a column.

```py
df['Is it valid?'] = np.where(df.index.isin(indexlist), 'Yes', 'No')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
      Name Country Is it valid?
0     John      BR          Yes
1    Peter      BR          Yes
2     Paul      BR           No
3    James      CZ           No
4  Jonatan      CZ          Yes
5    Maria      DK           No
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use iloc

```
df['Is it valid?']='No'
df['Is it valid?'].iloc[indexlist] = 'Yes'
```